# How read ImageView margin programmatically?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have an ImageView which is written in a layout file and looks like this

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/news_image" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dip"
            android:background="#aaaaaa" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I read the android:layout_marginLeft attribute in my Activity?

I tried this following code but `LayoutParams` of my `ImageView` doesn't have any margin members (like for example `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` has).

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.news_image);
LayoutParams lp = imageView.getLayoutParams();

int marginLeft = lp.marginLeft; // DON'T do this! It will not work 
                                // cause there is no member called marginLeft
```

Any suggestions how to get the margin from a `ImageView`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you have to cast the `LayoutParams` to the type that is specific to the layout the view is in. That is, being your view inside a `LinearLayout`, you'll have to do the following:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.news_image);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
```

now `lp` will let you access `margin*` fields.

Comment: Thank you! This works. I couldn't find anything in the Android documentation. Maybe I just looked at the wrong places.

Answer (score 6):

Your sol for it is as below:

---

```
 LinearLayout. LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

  int i=lp.leftMargin;
```